# Is there a shorthand for modulation in reverse?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Say I have array indices 0 through 5

If I'm incrementing a counter over this array, I could do something like

```
i % 6
```

To make sure it never goes out of index. Is there a shorthand notation for the same thing for decrementing? I'm asking in general, not specific to any language

I know I can do

```
if (i < 0) i = 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive integer `n` and non-negative counter `i`, you can define increment and decrement of the counter modulo `n` as arithmetic operations with positive integer values. Increment is `i = (i + 1) % n`, and decrement is `i = (i + n - 1) % n`.

Answer (score 0):

In some languages, `i % 6` would still work even when decrementing - they define negative%positive as positive, so you get 5 when i decrements to -1.

In any language, `(i + 6) % 6` would stay in range whether you increment or decrement.

Answer (score 0):

If your chosen language supports modular arithmetic for user-defined types then incrimenting or decrimenting a modular integer will result in a value within the range of that modular integer.

Ada allows the user to specify modular types. The Ada solution for your question is

```
type Index_type is mod 6;
type Example is array(Index_Type) of Integer;
```

Iteration through the array, treating it as a circular buffer, can be done with a simple loop

```
declare 
   I : Index_Type := 0;
   A : Example;
begin
   loop
      A(I) := some_value;
      I := I - 1;
   end loop;
end;
```

Within the loop I can be incremented or decremented, and the arithmetic will always be modulo 6 in this case. In Ada such circular buffers are sometimes used in producer/consumer patterns. In that case there are separate read and write indices, with a check for a buffer full condition upon each write and a check for a buffer empty condition upon each read.